# Angular 5 socket.io not recieving update in other component

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

**Context**: I have an angular application with a backend in nodejs. I have a feed that will update when I recieve a message from the server. When new data is inserted the server is notified, but my other component does not recieve anything. I have implemented the socket in a service that is injected into both components.

My server is build like this:

```
const port = 3000;
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('New Connection..')
socket.on('action', (data) => {

switch(data) {
  case 'new_odds':
  socket.emit('refresh_odds', 'UPDATE FEED! (FROM SERVER)')
  break;
  case 'new_results':
  break; 
}
});
});
//listen on port omitted
```

My service in angular:

```
const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

constructor() {

}


private socket;

public initSocket(): void {
    this.socket = socketIo(SERVER_URL);
}

public disconnectSocket(): void {
  this.socket.disconnect();
}

public send(action: Action): void {
    this.socket.emit('action', action);
}

public onOddsMessage(): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>(observer => {
        this.socket.on('refresh_odds', (data:string) => {
          observer.next(data)
        });
    });
}

public onEvent(event: Event): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<Event>(observer => {
        this.socket.on(event, () => observer.next());
    });
}
}
```

My feed component uses the socket service to listen for emits:

```
constructor(private _socket : SocketService) {
}

ngOnInit() {

this.initIoConnection();
}

private initIoConnection(): void {
  this._socket.initSocket();


this.ioConnection = this._socket.onOddsMessage()
  .subscribe((data: string) => {
    console.log('Recieved data from oddsMessage')
    //this.loadBetFeed();
  });
}
```

In a different component also using the service I'm trying to emit to the socket on the server. It does recieve the message on the server and emit a new message but my feed component does NOT pick up on this

```
testSocket() {
  //NOTIFY SERVER THAT IT SHOULD TELL CLIENTS TO REFRESH
  console.log('Test Socket Clicked')
  this._socket.initSocket();
  this._socket.send(Action.ODDS);
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong - I am using a shared service. Even if the components use different socket connections it shouldn't matter since they're listening for the same emits? I've tested in 2 browser tabs and also in incognito. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was emitting to the **socket** instead of the **server** which means only the current connection could see it.

New server:

```
 io.on('connect', (socket) => {
console.log('Connected client on port %s.', port);
socket.on('action', (data) => {
    io.emit('refresh_odds', 'UPDATE FEED! (FROM SERVER)') <-- changed socket to io
});
}
```